# Firebase data structure modeling to eliminate redundancy update or delete

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Good Day everyone I been working on E-Commerce App using Firebase I have no problem on the design (UI) and coding it except on how to properly structure nodes in Firebase. In relational database its easy but in Firebase I'm relatively new. Below is my tables in relational database format look like. How do I convert this to Firebase structure model? So I can eliminate redundancy in update/delete. Thank you and Good Day!

[image]

Comment: What have you designed so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sample

This is the way i like to keep the data. Keeps the Query Simple and Fast.

[image: Sample Database]

You can also create the structure like the relational databases have but you might need to special function to fetch the data and contact the infromation together.